# Eclipse Mars disable 'revert file' button

Tags: eclipse

When I right click and go to save my class I have accidentally clicked this a couple of times, making it rather annoying. Is there a way I can move/disable this option?

Answer (score 1):

If you are talking about the Revert menu item on the File menu, you can remove it by customizing the current perspective.  To do this:

```
Open Window=>Perspectives=>Customize Perspective
Select Menu Visibility tab
Click the '>' in front of File
Uncheck the Revert item
Click OK
```

Comment: This works but not exactly what I was looking for. I meant when I right clicked on the class window, how it has `Undo Typing, Revert File, and Save`. That's where I wanted to remove the revert file option.

Comment: Oh, sorry,   I generally don't save that way.  You would think that the above setting would be propagated to popup menu.